# how to locate link having href as java script function in selenium using java lang

Tags: selenium

need to locate libraries and color colorway
[image]

hello , 
I am new to selenium. please suggest how to locate links highlighted in image using selenium.
I have tried `linktext()` but not it is not working.

This is the HTML :

```
<DIV class=BlueBox><DIV class=BlueBoxHeader><IMG width=4 height=4 src="/Windchill/rfa/images/blue_topleft.gif"></DIV> <DIV class=BoxContent><!-- Start Title --> <DIV style="OVERFLOW: hidden"> <TABLE width="90%" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0> <TBODY> <TR> <TD class=BlueHeader style="PADDING-LEFT: 10px"><A href="javascript:toggleExpandableDiv('librariesContent', 'librariesContentIcon');"><SPAN style="PADDING-RIGHT: 4px"><IMG id=librariesContentIcon src="/Windchill/netmarkets/images/expand_tree.png" border=0 valign="bottom"></SPAN>Libraries</A> </TD></TR >
```

thanks!

Comment: consider adding code instead of image or screen shot.

Comment: <DIV class=BlueBox><DIV class=BlueBoxHeader><IMG width=4 height=4 src="/Windchill/rfa/images/blue_topleft.gif"></DIV>
<DIV class=BoxContent><!-- Start Title -->
<DIV style="OVERFLOW: hidden">
<TABLE width="90%" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=BlueHeader style="PADDING-LEFT: 10px"><A href="javascript:toggleExpandableDiv('librariesContent', 'librariesContentIcon');"><SPAN style="PADDING-RIGHT: 4px"><IMG id=librariesContentIcon src="/Windchill/netmarkets/images/expand_tree.png" border=0 valign="bottom"></SPAN>Libraries</A> </TD></TR

Comment: *"tried linktext() but not working"* Show **how** you tried and what does *"not working"* means

Comment: driver.findElement(By.linkText("Libraries")).click();

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with link text == Libraries (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 678 milliseconds

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("sidebarframe"))); 
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Libraries")).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**linkText** works for **text** between the **anchor** tags.

I can see partial linkText which is **Libraries**

code :

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Libraries")).click();
```

**UPDATE 1 :**

You can try this xpath also :

```
//a[contains(@href,'javascript:toggleExpandableDiv(')]
```

code would be :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'javascript:toggleExpandableDiv(')]")).click();
```

**UPDATE 2** :

As OP has mentioned that there is a frameset available and desired element is present in that.

You will have to switch the focus of your driver to interact with your desired element.for that you can use this code :

```
driver().switchTo().frame(driver().findElement(By.name("sidebarframe"))); 
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Libraries")).click();
```

Comment: thanks for answers got below - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //a[contains(@href,'javascript:toggleExpandableDiv(')] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.09 seconds

Comment: @priya : check for iframe, these type of error usually come from iframe.

Comment: for partiallinktext got same - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with partial link text == Libraries (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 445 milliseconds

Comment: right click on webpage then select inspect element , then CTRL+F , and search for //iframe

Comment: and check whether your desired element is inside an iframe.

Comment: exactly what for iframe ?

Comment: there can be iframe and may be your my group element can be inside of that , in that case you have to make sure you are switching focus of your driver.

Comment: <frameset name="mainframeset"
  <frameset name "contentFrameSet"
    <frameset name "sidebarframe"
       <html>
          <body class="xnavigatorBody"
            <form name=MAINFoRM"
              <div id="siteNavigator"
                <div class="BlueBox"
                  <div class="BoxContent"
                    <div class="BlueBody"
                      <div class="BlueBox"
                        <div class="Boxcontent"
                          <div class="LABEL"
                           <A href="javascript:bomSearch()">BOM</A>

Comment: @priya Update this _HTML_ within your question for further analysis

Comment: Yes you will need to switch the focus of your driver to the frame then you can interact with the my group element

Comment: driver.switchTo.frame(driver.findElement(by.name(“mainframeset”)));

Comment: @priya : I have updated my answer in update2 section , kindly check and let us know the status whether it worked for you or not .

Comment: Many thanks , its working now - driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("sidebarframe")));driver.findElement(By.linkText("Libraries")).click();

Comment: just ,I used linktext() instead of partiallinktext(), rest is same

Comment: yes but you needed to switch to right frame to interact with it , right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
//td[@class='BlueHeader']//a
```

Comment: thanks but its not helping , it is list link like  libraries -> BOM , Color , etc...can we use href stuff to locate or any other way ? , I am trying to click on libraries link[which is on left content box of site ] immediately after windows authentication login on site

Comment: This is locating <a>, Share the error stack which you are getting by using this.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //td[@class='BlueHeader']//a (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 798 milliseconds

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='BlueHeader']//a"));

Comment: Please debug and check, whether you are on correct way to locate element Or Wait needed OR  iFrame causing. Also, on locator what do you wants to achieve, Click or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Xpath** :

```
//a[normalize-space()='Libraries']
```

Comment: @priya : let me if you face any issue

Comment: thanks but its not helping , it is list link like  libraries -> BOM , Color , etc...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //a[normalize-space()='Libraries'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 516 milliseconds

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Libraries']"));

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath selector for selecting these three highlighted elements :

```
"//a[contains(.,'Libraries')] | //a[contains(.,'Calendar')] | //a[contains(.,'Color')]"
```

It will give a list of 3 elements

It will work for you.
Please do let me know if any issue occurs.

The logic is that you have to use "OR" condition if you want to get these elements.

Check for iframe existence as suggested by other answers and than try to get elements using this selector

Comment: xception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //span[contains(.,'Libraries')] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 765 milliseconds

Comment: tried driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Libraries')]"));

Comment: "//a[contains(.,'Libraries')] | //a[contains(.,'Calendar')] | //a[contains(.,'Color')]"

Comment: I think the "Libraries" text is present in anchor tag. So try to replace span with "a" tag

Comment: did it worked for you or still you are getting the issue ?

Comment: its working with below code -  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("sidebarframe")));driver.findElement(By.linkText("Libraries")).click();